# Why does my text in html not move?

Tags: jquery, html, css, text

I'm currently coding a website, and I'm trying to put text under the banner along with other elements but nothing seems to be going down.

https://gyazo.com/379cfa01780dddc112d06bd53a38e04b
https://gyazo.com/c67ba5499d4ce188946094978f346c6a

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.min.css'> 
<style>
#topBanner {
    position: relative;
}

#topBanner  {
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#topBanner:after {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 180px #defeec;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 360px #defeec; /* THIS PARAGRAPH CONTROLS SOME FADE ON THE BANNER */
    box-shadow: inset 180px 0 400px #defeec;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* _______________________________________________________________________________________________________ */

#body {
    background: url(stardust.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-position: right;
}

#container-narrow {
    margin-top: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 2000px;
}

body {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#hCharacter {
    margin-top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'ChunkFive';
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: red;
    z-index: 999;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive';
    src: url('ChunkFive.otf') format: 'opentype';
}  
</style>

</head>
<body id='body'>
    <div id='container-narrow'></div>
    <div id=topBanner>
        <img src="LOGO%20Mockup.jpg" width=1920px height=400px></img>
    </div>   
    <div id=hCharacter>Characters</div>

    <p> Characters</p>
    <script> $.backstretch('/bgImage'); </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: your css style are absolutely wrong. what is "container-narrow" ?  and use any of good IDE for coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead ... minor adjustments needed but it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'>   </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.min.css'> 

 <style>




    #topBanner {
  position: relative;
}

   #topBanner  {
 display: block;
 margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
  }

  #topBanner:after {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 180px #defeec;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 360px #defeec;                 /* THIS       PARAGRAPH CONTROLS SOME FADE ON THE BANNER */
 box-shadow: inset 180px 0 400px #defeec;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

/* _______________________________________________________________________________________________________ */

```
    #body {
background: url(stardust.png) repeat 0 0;
background-position: right;
  }

       #container-narrow {
        margin-top: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        height: 2000px;
    }

    body {
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
            min-height: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    }


    #hCharacter {
        margin-top: 50%;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'ChunkFive';
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: center; 
        color: red;
        z-index: 999;
    }




    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ChunkFive';
        src: url('ChunkFive.otf') format: 'opentype';

    }  


    </style>

  </head>
    <body id='body'>
    <div id='container-narrow'>
    <div id=topBanner>
    <img src="LOGO%20Mockup.jpg" width=1920px height=400px></img>

    </div>

<div id=hCharacter>Characters</div>

 <p> Characters</p>

</div>
    <script>

$.backstretch('/bgImage');

      </script>

   </body>
```

Comment: Awesome I really appreciate it, im really noob when it comes to coding, you mind telling me what you did so I can learn from this?

Comment: I changed the div closing from the container narrow to be nested into the characters so it can display it underneath

Comment: also the attributes are in double quotes not single. ( inline attributes html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
#container-narrow {
    margin-top: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

You're setting the height which is pushing the text out of the frame. Set it to `auto` or set it shorter to fix it.

https://jsbin.com/wunadu/1/edit

Comment: Thanks really appreciate, do you also know why the attributes arent working on my text? :/

Comment: There's a few things going on wrong there, and without remaking it entirely I don't think I could fix that. Off the top of my head I did notice you were setting the `height` of the `#topbanner` to 100% which will fill the entire screen, and putting the `::after` outside the screen. However, when I tried that it still didn't work, so there something else going on there.

I would recommend starting with just tiding up a bit; combine your `#topbanner` tags, look into usage for the `::after` selector, etc: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp